# Conditional type on generic function: Type is not assignable

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to constrain the return type of a generic function. (Example boiled down for simplicity, please ignore the actual 'usefulness' of the function).

```js
type MyReturnType<T> = T extends string ? number : Function;
type Input = string | number;
function myFn<T extends string | number>(input: T): MyReturnType<T> {
  return typeof input === 'string' ? 100 : (() => {});
}
```

But the `return` statement causes a typescript error –

```
Type '100 | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MyReturnType<T>'.
  Type '100' is not assignable to type 'MyReturnType<T>'.
```

– which got me really confused. In my understanding, `MyReturnType<T>` can **only resolve to a number or Function**. How can 100 be not assignable? Am I getting something wrong here? What is the compiler trying to tell me?

I feel like the answer might be in the [docs for conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), but I cannot find it (quite honestly, some parts of the docs here went a bit over my head). Could someone please explain to me what's going on in this snippet?

---

(TS 3.8.3)

Comment: Looks to me like: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735

Comment: @Lesiak thanks for your comment! The problem actually also occurs for non-boolean values, I adjusted the question to reflect that.
The way I read [mhegazy's comment on that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735#issuecomment-376960435), this is a design limitation of the compiler, which right now requires a type cast to avoid it. Do you share this view? Would you care to make an answer (since you dug up the issue)? Otherwise, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like compiler limitation for type narrowing to union types:

[Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T2 extends keyof T1 ? true : false' #22735](http://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735)

Answer (score 0):

The actual working solution here is to use overloads:

```
type Input = string | number;
function myFn(input: string): number
function myFn(input: number): Function
function myFn(input: Input): number | Function {
    return typeof input === "string" ? 100 : () => {}
}
```

Just make sure you write one to cover every input type possibility. In my case, where my argument had 5 possible types (which includes 2 unions) I had to write it like this:

```
type Value = string | number | null
export function divBy10toPow(value: string, power: number): number
export function divBy10toPow(value: null, power: number): null
export function divBy10toPow(value: number, power: number): number
export function divBy10toPow<T extends number | null>(value: T, power: number): T
export function divBy10toPow<T extends string | null>(value: T, power: number): T extends string ? number : null
export function divBy10toPow(value: Value, power: number): Value {
    return value === null
        ? null
        : BigNumber(value)
            .div(10 ** power)
            .toNumber()
}
```

You have to account for the specific unions of `string | null` and `number | null`, otherwise it will not type your return values correctly.